# How to create directory in django media file (best way)?

Tags: python, django, urllib, file-not-found

I want to save downloaded images to a path that like so: media/images/[user.pk]/ directly from urlretrieve from urllib library is that possible and what is the most elegant way?

This are the used code snippets:

- here I use urlretrieve with path like .../media/images/[user.pk]/[filename.jpg]

  ```
  file_path, header = urlretrieve(image_url, os.path.join(
                      MEDIA_ROOT, get_image_path(
                         self, 'profile_image_'+str(
                           datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M"))+'.jpg
  ```
- Here is the defined function that returns desired path with filename

  ```
  def get_image_path(instance, filename):
      return os.path.join('images', str(instance.pk), filename)
  ```

when I run I get an error since the file does not exists:

FileNotFoundError at /rest/oauth2/google
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\xampp\htdocs\BookProjectFresh\media\images\21\profile_image_20160723_0801.jpg'

I know I can achieve that by first loading file into temp folder and then load from there and put into the django model and it will automatically create file path if it does not exists, but then I have 2 files on my pc with same content. Or would be the best way to do it with os.path.makedirs? Please if you know any other way share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved a problem like so:

```
def save_image_from_url(self, image_url):
        if self.profile_image_url  != image_url or not os.path.isfile(self.profile_image.path):
            if not os.path.exists(get_image_path(self, os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, get_image_path(
                self, '')))):
                os.makedirs(get_image_path(self, os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, get_image_path(
                self, ''))))

            self.profile_image_url = image_url

            file_path, header = urlretrieve(image_url, os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, get_image_path(
                self, 'profile_image_'+str(datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M"))+'.jpg')))

            self.profile_image = file_path
            self.save()
```